# Why my mysqldb code is not working? No error message, no data

Tags: python, linux, web-scraping, debian, mysql-python

I wrote a web-scraping script what I save into an excel file and after upload this excel file to my MySQL DB server. I haven't got any error message, but the table is empty in the MySQL. Why? What am I wrong?

Here the mysqldb part:

```
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='database1')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """ load data local infile '/usr/src/Python-2.7.13/output.csv' 
    into table ARRIVALS
    character set latin1
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\r\n'
    ignore 1 lines;
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()

    time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are working in linux, and the file is composed in linux, the linebreak should probably be \n instead of \r\n. This probably causes your file to be read as a single line, which is ignored, as specified in your query